# Invalid response object from API: 'Unsupported data type\n' (HTTP response code was 400)

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, azure-openai, azure-ai

im trying to Create a python program that uses OpenAI API to answer user questions on custom/proprietary data. im using azure open ai api key and below is the code

```
 import os
    import numpy as np
    from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
    import faiss
    import nltk
    import openai
    import pandas as pd
    import openai
    openai.api_type = "azure"
    openai.api_base = ""
    openai.api_version = "2023-05-15"
    openai.api_key = ""
nltk.download('punkt')
content_folder = 'C:\AccessNotDeniedFolder\content'
model = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2')

def embed_text(text):
    return model.encode([text])[0]

embeddings = []
file_paths = []

for filename in os.listdir(content_folder):
    file_path = os.path.join(content_folder, filename)
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        content = file.read()

    chunks = nltk.sent_tokenize(content)
    for chunk in chunks:
        embeddings.append(embed_text(chunk))
        file_paths.append(file_path)
vector_dim = len(embeddings[0])

index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(vector_dim)

embeddings = np.array(embeddings, dtype=np.float32)

index.add(embeddings)
user_query = "Your user query goes here"

query_embedding = embed_text(user_query)

_, top_k = index.search(np.array([query_embedding], dtype=np.float32), k=5)

selected_embeddings = embeddings[top_k[0]]
context = ' '.join([str(chunk) for chunk in selected_embeddings])
prompt = f""" Answer the following user query using the context provided.  
USER QUERY: {user_query}  
CONTEXT: 
{context}  
"""
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    language="en",
    engine="gpt35",
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=100,
    text=prompt)
response_text = response['responses'][0]['content']
print(response_text)
```

im getting the APIError: Invalid response object from API: 'Unsupported data type\n' (HTTP response code was 400) error,  im completely new here and still learning help me resolve this

i have a openai resource group created and took the key and endpoint from there i have deployed a gpt-35-turbo model and have taken the model name from the deployed model name.

Comment: can you check the type of your 'prompt' item before calling "openai.ChatCompletion.create"?